# cast anonymous type to an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, anonymous-types

This doesn't seem to be possible?  So what is the best work-around?  Expando / dynamic?

```
public interface ICoOrd {
    int x { get; set; }
    int y { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
ICoOrd a = new {x = 44, y = 55};
```

ref:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx  (Jon's suggestion)

Comment: I'm just curious: what are you trying to do that would require you to do this? If you know the interface, you obviously know what functionality the interface has, so you can implement a class to provide that functionality in which case you don't need an anonymous type anymore, since you can just create an instance of your class.

Comment: Why would your want cast anonymous(You don't "care" about it's design) to an Interface(which mean you do "care" about it's design)?

Comment: @gdoron: an interface is a handy thing to have, and I've found that good use of anon types (no LINQ in this case) has simplified my code *and* helped with making the intention clearer.  That's the motivation.  Mostly to do with intermediate structures.

Comment: Try f#, it does something similar to what you described using type inference.

Comment: @corvidae: thanks.  I have been recently.  Quite like it actually.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The best "workaround" is to create and use a normal, "named" type that implements the interface.

But if you insist that an anonymous type be used, consider using a dynamic interface proxy framework like [`ImpromptuInterface`](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/).

```
 var myInterface =  new { x = 44, y = 55 }.ActLike<ICoOrd>();
```

Comment: +1 for ImpromptuInterface. You can also look at Clay (clay.codeplex.com)

Comment: Another solution: use F#.  You can use an object expression to create an object that implements an interface without explicitly creating a named class.

Comment: @phoog: sometimes I think it'd be good if you could have a mixed language project.  Perhaps this'd introduce too many headaches though.

Answer (score 9):

No, anonymous types never implement interfaces. `dynamic` wouldn't let you cast to the interface either, but *would* let you just access the two properties. Note that anonymous types are `internal`, so if you want to use them across assemblies using `dynamic`, you'll need to use `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Comment: +1:  ty.  I did a little reading up on InternalsVisibleTo (MS link now in question).  That is helpful.  It looks a little labour intensive.  Have you seen InternalsVisibleTo used in the field?

Comment: @sgtz: Labour intensive? It's a single attribute. It takes a little bit more work if you're using strongly typed assemblies, but otherwise it's very simple. I use it a lot for unit tests.

Comment: @sgtz: InternalsVisibleTo is normally used for unit testing; sometimes you want to do unit testing of an internal class but want the test assembly to be a different assembly. So you give the test assembly access to the internals.  It is rarely used in production code scenarios. Remember, assemblies are *versionable*; that's the whole *point* of assemblies. Under most circumstances you would not want to *independently change the versions* of two assemblies *that see each other's internals*. If you have two assemblies that need to see each others internals, consider merging them into one.

Comment: @EricLippert: that use case makes perfect sense.  ty.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question and answers but I stumbled on this on this looking to do exactly the same thing for some unit tests. I then occurred to me that I am already doing something like this using Moq (facepalm).

I do like the other suggestion for ImpromptuInterface but I am already using Moq and feel like it having a larger following (that is opinion and not fact) will be more stable and supported longer.

so for this case would be something like

```
public interface ICoOrd
{
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{

    public void Test()
    {
        var aCord = new Mock<ICoOrd>();
        aCord.SetupGet(c => c.X).Returns(44);
        aCord.SetupGet(c => c.Y).Returns(55);

        var a = aCord.Object;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: just adding another way to mock the cord, started doing it this way and like it a little better.

```
public void AnotherTest()
{
    var aCord = Mock.Of<ICoOrd>(c => c.X == 44 && c.Y == 55);
    //do stuff with aCord
}
```