# List anonymous type to List of interface

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically implementing an interface in .NET 4.0 (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974736/dynamically-implementing-an-interface-in-net-4-0-c)
>   [cast anonymous type to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249645/cast-anonymous-type-to-an-interface)

Is there a way to "cast" an anonymous type to a specific interface ? I know I can create a class who implement this interface but I don't need this class, I have to return an interface.

I need a solution without third party library

Thanks,

```
var result =
    (from a in context.TABLE1
     join b in context.TABLE2 on a.Table2Id equals b.Id
     select new
     {
         Table1Field1 = a.Field1,
         Table2Field1 = b.Field1,
         ....
     }).ToList<IMyClass>();

public interface IMyClass
{
    string Table1Field1 { get; set; }
    string Table1Field2 { get; set; }
    string Table2Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249645/cast-anonymous-type-to-an-interface

Comment: I saw this post but use the external lib, not allowed here.

Comment: If you would have read a bit more you would have seen Jon Skeet's answer saying that it's not possible :)

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible. Why? Because an anonymous type is a syntactic sugar. Anonymous types are a design-time feature meaning that compiler will generate an actual type with a very strange name, but it's like any other type after all.

Sadly, C# doesn't have interface auto-implementation. That is, you need to implement an interface in a *named* type.

**UPDATE**

Want to workaround this limitation?

You can use inversion of control (either using an API like Castle Windsor or just *by hand*).

Check this sample code I made just now:

```
public static class AnonymousExtensions
{
    public static T To<T>(this object anon)
    {
        // #1 Obtain the type implementing the whole interface
        Type implementation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                .GetTypes()
                                .SingleOrDefault(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T)));

        // #2 Once you've the implementation type, you create an instance of it
        object implementationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(implementation, false);

        // #3 Now's time to set the implementation properties based on
        // the anonyous type instance property values!
        foreach(PropertyInfo property in anon.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            // Has the implementation this anonymous type property?
            if(implementation.GetProperty(property.Name) != null)
            {
                // Setting the implementation instance property with the anonymous
                // type instance property's value!
                implementation.GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(implementationInstance, property.GetValue(anon, null));
            }
        }

        return (T)implementationInstance;
    }
}
```

Design and implement some interface...

```
// Some interface
public interface IHasText
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}

// An implementation for the interface
public class HasText : IHasText
{
    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now use the whole extension method somewhere!

```
var anonymous = new { Text = "Hello world!" };
IHasText hasTextImplementation = anonymous.To<IHasText>();
```

`hasTextImplementation` will have a `HasText` implementation instance! Or in other words: `Text` property will contain **Hello world!**.

Note that this code can be tweaked in order to support base and abstract classes, but I believe that this is enough to get the basic information to improve it as you want and for your needs.