# Assign to interface array initializator compiles but why?

Tags: c#

Today I was thinking it would be neat to make anonymous object which is type of some interface, and I have seen on SO that I am not only one.

Before I started checking out what happens I wrote some code like the one below.
To my amusement it compiled, I am using .net framework 4 and I know there is no way to do anonymous objects implement interface, but I have not seen complaint from VS about this code.

Even better when I put braces intelisense is finding "Property" of my interface, just like it would be valid code.

Why is this piece compiling and when ran it is giving null reference exception?

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Holder holder = new Holder { someInterface = { Property = 1 } };
            Console.WriteLine(holder.someInterface.Property);
        }
    }

    class Holder
    {
        public ISomeInterface someInterface{get; set;}
    }

    interface ISomeInterface
    {
        int Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Holder holder = new Holder { someInterface = { Property = 1 } };//<--Note you missed new keyword
```

Above line is equal to

```
Holder temp = new Holder();
temp.someInterface.Property = 1;
Holder holder = temp;// <--Here someInterface is null so you get null reference exception.
```

This should be something like

```
Holder holder = new Holder { someInterface = new SomeClass(){ Property = 1 } };//<--Note the new keyword here
```

Note: Your code never introduced "Anonymous Type" It is an "Object Initializer".

When you use ObjectInitializer syntax with `new` keyword it means you're **setting** something, when you use ObjectInitializer syntax without  `new` keyword it means you're **reading** something.

Comment: Good answer. FYI, this can absolutely be done with an awesome third party library I just found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249645/cast-anonymous-type-to-an-interface

Comment: +1 Just for sake of completeness this is described in C# 5.0 specs at **§7.6.10.1** and **§7.6.10.2**.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That was good chunk of code I found last week while looking for some feature like that:)

Comment: @Adriano Thanks, I wonder how you guys point exact part of the specification! Sometimes I don't even know what's the exact name of the feature :(

Comment: A small correction, this is equivalent to `Holder temp = new Holder(); temp.someInterface.Property = 1; Holder holder = temp;`.  The property assignment happens *before* `holder` is initialized. Imagine if `holder` were a static field; you would not expect the property to be able to read that field and get the new object, right?

Answer (score 2):

> it would be neat to make anonymous object which is type of some interface,
>
> I know there is no way to do anonymous objects implement interface, but I have not seen complaint from VS about this code.

The problem is, you're assuming that the following code creates a new instance of an anonymous type

```
new Holder { someInterface = { Property = 1 } };
```

`{ Property = 1 }` does not create a new instance of an anonymous type - this is an object initializer.

If you do replace your code with a proper instantiation of an anonymous type, then the compiler will complain that the instance cannot be implicitly converted to `ISomeInterface`, like you expected.

```
new Holder { someInterface = new { Property = 1 } };
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting why the compiler lets this behaviour. The reason being `someInterface` need not be `null` always. This is what object initializer syntax is translated to:

```
Holder temp = new Holder(); //creates temp object calling default constructor
temp.someInterface = yourValue;
holder = temp; //finally assigned back to your variable.
```

In your case `someInterface` is left uninitialized. But it need not be the case if you have your empty constructor initializing `someinterface` correctly.

```
class Holder
{
    public Holder()
    {
       someInterface = new Class();
    }

    public ISomeInterface someInterface{get; set;}
}
```

Now this works:

```
Holder holder = new Holder { someInterface = { Property = 1 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign an instance to someInterface in Holder constractor; otherwise, it will be null.

Comment: `someInterface` is initialized to an invalid value - which is the point of the question "why does this compile"?