# Why Collection Initialization Throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, collections, nullreferenceexception, duck-typing

The following code throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
internal class Foo
{
    public Collection<string> Items { get; set; } // or List<string>
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo()
            {
                Items = { "foo" } // throws NullReferenceException
            };
    }
}
```

1. Why don't collection initiliazers work in this case, although `Collection<string>` implements the `Add()` method, and why is NullReferenceException is thrown?
2. Is it possible to get the collection initializer working, or is `Items = new Collection<string>() { "foo" }` the only correct way to initialize it?

Comment: have you tried using `new` when initializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never instantiated `Items`. Try this.

```
new Foo()
    {
        Items = new Collection<string> { "foo" }
    };
```

To answer your second question: You need to add a constructor and initialize `Items` over there.

```
internal class Foo
{    
    internal Foo()
    {
        Items  = new Collection<string>();
    }
    public Collection<string> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

[Why your code throws NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684415/assign-to-interface-array-initializator-compiles-but-why/20684533#20684533)?

Comment: This does not answer his question, see #2.

Comment: @mxmissile Updating my answer, check now

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys. As summary **collection initializer doesn't create instance of collection itself, but just uses Add() to add items to existant instance**, and throws NullReferenceException if instance doesn't exist

1.

```
internal class Foo
{    
    internal Foo()
    {
        Items  = new Collection<string>();
    }
    public Collection<string> Items { get; private set; }
}

var foo = new Foo()
                {
                    Items = { "foo" } // foo.Items contains 1 element "foo"
                };
```

2.

```
   internal class Foo
    {    
        internal Foo()
        {
            Items  = new Collection<string>();
            Items.Add("foo1");
        }
        public Collection<string> Items { get; private set; }
    }

    var foo = new Foo()
                    {
                        Items = { "foo2" } // foo.Items contains 2 elements: "foo1", "foo2"
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Foo` constructor you want to initialize collection.

```
internal class Foo
{
    public Foo(){Items = new Collection(); }
    public Collection<string> Items { get; set; } // or List<string>
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo()
            {
                Items = { "foo" } // throws NullReferenceException
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.Items` is declared, but an instance of `Collection` has never been assigned, so `.Items` is `null`.

Fix:

```
internal class Foo
{
    public Collection<string> Items { get; set; } // or List<string>
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo()
            {
                Items = new Collection<string> { "foo" } // no longer throws NullReferenceException :-)
            };
    }
}
```