# Anonymous types for simple interfaces with only one implementation

Tags: c#, .net, interface, anonymous-types

Let's suppose I have the following the interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
     A MyA { get; }
     B MyB { get; }
     C MyC { get; }
}
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are three non-related classes, and don't implement `IMyInterface` in any way.

Let's suppose now that I will only have one implementation for this interface. I might have wanted to create it for mocking purposes, even if it's just composed of properties.

I have designed the following factory:

```
public static class MyManagerFactory {
    public static IMyManager CreateMyManager() {
        //Return the implementation
    }
}
```

I don't want to create a whole new file and type for just an implementation of properties, so I was looking for an anonymous type:

```
var anon = new {
    MyA = new A(),
    MyB = new B(),
    MyC = new C()
};
```

But I cannot return `anon` because it's of type `object` and the compiler can't know I'm implementing my interface.

So I thought of doing a cast:

```
IMyInterface casted = anon as IMyInterface;
```

But this won't compile either, stating:

> Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'IMyInterface' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion.

I thought the `as` conversion is supposed to be done at runtime, and if (for any reason) fails, it would simply return `null`.

But this error is compile time.

How can I return a `IMyInterface` instance?

Comment: You can't - you have to create a new class and implement the interface. You don't need to put it in its own file however.

Comment: Does it **have** to be an interface? Can't you just change it to a class and instantiate the class instead of an anonymous type?

Comment: Anonymous types cannot implement an interface: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface

Comment: @MikeEason The interface will be injected to the client/consumer, and it will also make my life easier when testing, so I was trying to avoid a concrete class

Comment: @MatiCicero I see, I think your question may [have already been answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249645/cast-anonymous-type-to-an-interface)

Comment: Have you considered mocking libraries? They offer a solution for this problem specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as the type does **not** implement the interface.
It just hasthe methods of the interface "by coincidence"

C# doesn't look if methods are presents it check if the type is defined as implementing the interface.

Answer (score 2):

> I might have wanted to create it for mocking purposes,
>
> I don't want to create a whole new file and type for just an implementation of properties, so I was looking for an anonymous type:

If it's just for mocking purposes, then you can just create a nested private implementation of that interface, no need for a whole new file

```
public class MyClassTests
{

    private class MyDummyImplementation : IMyInterface { ... }    

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var x = new MyDummyImplementation();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a nice feature or not, but currently C# doesn't support anonymously-implemented interface on anonymous objects.

If you look for further info, you'll see that Java has this feature (for example see this Q&A here in StackOverflow: [How can an anonymous class use "extends" or "implements"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848510/how-can-an-anonymous-class-use-extends-or-implements)).

At least C# 6 won't include this feature. From my point of view, it could be very useful and in my humble opinion, it's the unique Java feature I would steal to implement in C#.

Comment: This won't be that easy: anonymous types cannot declare member methods. So how would you implement an interface that has some methods?

Comment: @Kryptos Dreaming is free. It's just a desire :D

Comment: @Kryptos Anyway, you can using delegates, can't you?

Comment: yes, but delegates are basically objects that encapsule a method. Your interface will still onyl be able to have properties. Note that I would also find this very useful. I will share your dream ;)

Comment: @Kryptos Wrong! `new { DoStuff = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine()) }`. We already have anonymous methods and delegate type inference :D

Comment: You are mistaken. `DoStuff` is not a method it is an instance of a delegate. If you could use an interface for anonymous type, it will have a property `Action DoStuff { get; set; }`, but not a method `void DoStuff()`

Comment: @Kryptos I know that. I mean, you can easily simulate methods in anonymous objects using delegates and anonymous methods :D

Comment: @Kryptos Since C# has a lot of syntactic sugar, I don't find hard that these anonymous objects with delegates would be compiled in a way that they could fullfill an interface contract. Why not. It's just speculation...